Testing with router.navigate stacks for each test
I have a ResumeApplicationComponent that calls a method on ngOnInit that loads data and conditionally navigates to a page in our app. After adding a few tests, I'm getting errors that router.navigate is calling navigate 5 times. Why is the router stacking these calls in my test?
Component:
export class ResumePageComponent implements OnInit {

  public applicationId: string = "";

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private applicationFacade: CustomerApplicationFacade,
    private routingFacade: RoutingFacade) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAndNavigate();
  }

  public loadAndNavigate(): void {
    this.applicationFacade.commandLoadApplication(this.applicationId).subscribe((success) => {
      if (success) {
        const step = this.applicationFacade.getResumeApplicationStep()
        const page = step > -1 ? applicationDescriptor.pages.find(a => a.index == step) : null;
        if (page) {
          if (step < 2) {
            //if application not started, go to landing page. 
            this.router.navigate(['/apply/' + page.route]);
          } else {
            this.routingFacade.determinePageOnResume(page.id);
          }
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/portal/dashboard']);
        }
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/portal/dashboard']);
      }
    });
  }
}

Test:
describe('ResumePageComponent', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<ResumePageComponent>;
  let component: ResumePageComponent;
  const customerApplicationFacade = createSpyObject(CustomerApplicationFacade);
  let routingFacade: SpyObject<RoutingFacade> = createSpyObject(RoutingFacade);
  let mockRouter: SpyObject<Router> = createSpyObject(Router);

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: ResumePageComponent,
    imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [ResumePageComponent],
    providers: [
      { provide: CustomerApplicationFacade, useValue: customerApplicationFacade },
      { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
      { provide: RoutingFacade, useValue: routingFacade },
      {
        provide: ActivatedRoute,
        useValue: {
          snapshot: {
            paramMap: {
              get: () => '1234',
            },
          },
        },
      }
    ]
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    customerApplicationFacade.commandLoadApplication.and.returnValue(of(true));
    spectator = createComponent();
    component = spectator.component;
    spyOn(component, 'loadAndNavigate').and.stub();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should navigate to dashboard if application is not loaded', () => {
    customerApplicationFacade.commandLoadApplication.and.returnValue(of(false));
    component.loadAndNavigate();
    expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/portal/dashboard']);
  });

  fit('should navigate to dashboard if page index not found', () => {
    customerApplicationFacade.getResumeApplicationStep.and.returnValue(of(9999));
    component.loadAndNavigate();
    expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/portal/dashboard']);
  });

  fit('should navigate to invite-begin if application step is 0', () => {
    customerApplicationFacade.getResumeApplicationStep.and.returnValue(of(0));
    component.loadAndNavigate();
    expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/apply/invite-begin']);
    expect(routingFacade.determinePageOnResume).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  fit('should navigate to begin if application step is 1', () => {
    customerApplicationFacade.getResumeApplicationStep.and.returnValue(of(1));
    component.loadAndNavigate();
    expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/apply/begin']);
    expect(routingFacade.determinePageOnResume).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  fit('should call determinePageOnResume when resume step is greater than 1', () => {
    customerApplicationFacade.getResumeApplicationStep.and.returnValue(of(2));
    component.loadAndNavigate();
    expect(routingFacade.determinePageOnResume).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});


I moved all of the logic and navigation out of ngOnInit into it's own method to reduce calls, but the router is not resetting in each test.

Any reason why you're not using RouterTestingModule.withRoutes?

@Pieterjan, No, I really just want to check that router.navigate calls the route I'm expecting. There are around 20 different pages it could route to. Do I need to define them all if that's all I'm checking?

You can use the below code to reset the spy for checking the latest value
 beforeEach(async () => {
     customerApplicationFacade.commandLoadApplication.and.returnValue(of(true));
     spectator = createComponent();
     component = spectator.component;
     
     routingFacade.determinePageOnResume.calls.reset(); // changed here!
     mockRouter.navigate.calls.reset(); // changed here!
    
     spyOn(component, 'loadAndNavigate').and.stub();
   });

